# Titanium HTTPClient call works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, titanium, httpclient

I am using http://www.realtime.co/ to send push notifications. Unfortuntately I am having an issue with the HTTPClient request. It works perfectly in the Simulator but it gives me an Error 400 on device.

I have checked the JSON string that is being sent and it's identical between the two. I have noticed in the past that when something works in the simulator and not on the device it often has to deal with capitalized letters, they seem to get resolved in the simulator but not on the device, i.e. an image file.

Anyone know what might be causing this issue? I suspect it's something in the headers but can't seem to figure it out. Could the headers, lower and uppercases be wrong? I can't seem to find any info on what the exact ones should be.

```
var url = 'https://ortc-mobilepush.realtime.co/mp/publish';

var notification =  {
    applicationKey: "[myKey]",
    privateKey: "[myPrivateKey]", 
    channel : "[channel]",
    message : "[message]", 
    //"payload" : { "sound" : "default", "badge" : "1"}
 };

var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("ORTC Sent text: " + this.responseText);
     },
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e);
     },
     timeout : 10000
 });

 // Prepare the connection.
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.setRequestHeader('charset', 'utf-8');

client.open("POST", url);
client.send(JSON.stringify(notification));
```

Comment: Did you check `this.responseText` in `onerror` callback? There could be some error message pointing to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is in the cap of the following line.

```
client.setRequestHeader('charset', 'utf-8');
```

Needs to be:

```
 client.setRequestHeader('Charset', 'utf-8');
```

The simulator seems to cope with it but the device doesn't this usually applies to everything even file paths, in Titanium.